# Where are GPS coordinates stored in a video taken with Galaxy S10 stock camera v9.0.05.29?

Tags: android, video, gps, samsung-galaxy, samsung-galaxy-camera

I have a Samsung Galaxy S10 and I am using the stock Camera app (com.sec.android.app.camera, version 9.0.05.29).
I have the "Location tags" enabled so that my phone correctly saves GPS coordinates to the photos I take.

This used to work also for .mp4 videos, so that the location was stored in the metadata tag "GPSCoordinates".
However, all my recent videos do not have such tag and hence their GPS coordinates are lost.

Digging back into my library, I figured out that the change occurred in July 2019:

- Firmware G973FXXU1ASE7 (Jun 2019): GPS data saved in .mp4 tag GPSCoordinates
- Firmware G973FXXU2ASF3 (Jul 2019): NO GPS data saved in the videos

If I take a recent .mp4 file:

1. The default Samsung Gallery app seems to be able to show the GPS location of the video while it is on the phone
2. Google Photos app shows the location, while Google Photos from the web shows no location
3. After transferring via USB the .mp4 to a PC, by using exiftool I cannot find any tag which has the GPS coordinates

Does anyone know if Samsung changed the metadata format?
Any idea on how to recover this piece of information from the stock .mp4 videos?

Comment: It can be that the info is stored in the MediaStore. I have a device where the pictures do not even get location tags in exif info but the MediaStore has it.

Comment: Same here with my OnePlus 8T

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

You have to go into those two apps:

- Settings > Apps > App Management > Photos > Permission > Storage

Set it to **Don't Allow** and then revert it back to **Allow management of all files**.

Then go to:

- Settings > Apps > App Management > Camera > Permission > Storage
- Settings > Apps > App Management > Camera > Permission > Location

and for both permissions do the same.

The problem is now fixed on Android 12 on OnePlus 8T